# ASP.NET Visual Studio - Go To Next Page ONLY If Next Page Exists

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I've built a UI using ASP.NET Core to allow users to import Excel files into a database and then view/edit the data that was imported. However, there seems to be some kind of update delay for the data to be viewable.

When the user imports a file, they are brought to a page that looks like this:
[image: After Import Page]

Any user that gets here should be able to just click the View/Edit button to move to the next step, but half of the time, an error like this pops up:

[image: Error'd Out Page]

Which is telling me that the import is not available, even though it is! (just take my word for it)

I attempted to fix this by trying to pull one of the objects from the import, but that doesn't work here, since the program seems to be successful in grabbing that object, and it then goes to the next page and errors out.

I'm using Razor Pages to build this, here is the frontend file:

```
@page "{count?}/{ID?}"
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/" />


<div class="justify-content-center">
    <h2 align="center" style="color:yellowgreen;">@Html.ValidationMessage("PageNotReady")</h2>
</div>

@if(Model.objectCount != 0)
{
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br />
    <h2 style="color:yellowgreen">Objects Imported: @Model.objectCount</h2>
    <br />

    <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="View/Edit" class="btn btn-dark" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.assessmentID" name="assessmentID" />
    </form>
</div>
}

<footer style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; padding-left: 10px">
    <p style="color: white;">Version 2.1</p>
</footer>
```

And here is the backend, where I try to pull an object to sense if the next page is available

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using KelderModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CustomerPageTest.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int objectCount { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int assessmentID { get; set; }

        public void OnGet(int? count, int? ID)
        {
            objectCount = Convert.ToInt32(count);
            assessmentID = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            KelderModel.Assessment testGrab = new KelderModel.Assessment();
            try
            {
                using(var context = new DataWarehouseContext())
                {
                    testGrab = context.Assessment
                        .Where(a => a.AssessmentId == assessmentID)
                        .First();
                }
                return RedirectToPage("/View/EditAssessment", new { assessmentId = testGrab.AssessmentId});
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("PageNotReady", "This Assessment Is Not Ready To View");
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the backend, you can see that the program tries to grab some related data, and if successful it routes to the next page, but if unsuccessful, reloads the page with an error message. That looks like this:

[image]

However, the picture above was made by typing in a URL that tried to pull something that definitely didn't exist. When the page errors out, the related data DOES exist but I have to wait 5 minutes or so to access it. How can I program this to disallow users to reach that error page and instead print out the error message?

Comment: which line is line #29 in that file?

Comment: try .FirstOrDefault(), then check whether it is NULL

Comment: @urlreader Using FirstOrDefault() would result in the same error. It won't return NULL but the data still wont be viewable.

Comment: if you check the error message, it is for OnGet. you did not return anything

Comment: If the error is in the EditAssessment class can you show that code?